# Duplicating Rows and calculating totals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay, So I have a table and I am trying to duplicate the rows and calculate the totals when the price and qty's are entered.

My table row is like so:

```
    <tr class="itemRow1">
        <td class="col-xs-2"><input class="form-control" name=
        "item_number[]" type="text" value=""></td>

        <td class="col-xs-2"><input class="form-control" name="item_name[]"
        type="text" value=""></td>

        <td class="col-xs-2"><input class="form-control" name=
        "item_description[]" type="text" value=""></td>

        <td class="col-xs-2"><input class="form-control price" name=
        "item_price[]" type="text" value=""></td>

        <td class="col-xs-2"><select class="form-control" name=
        "item_tax[]">
            <option value="1">
                Yes
            </option>

            <option value="0">
                No
            </option>
        </select></td>

        <td class="col-xs-1"><input class="form-control qty" name=
        "item_qty[]" type="text" value=""></td>

        <td class="col-xs-1"><input class="form-control total" disabled
        name="item_total[]" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
```

I then have the duplicating javascript that finds the inputs in the row and clears them from the previous entry.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#newRow").click(function() {
    var count = $('#itemTable tbody tr').length + 1;
    $("#itemTable .itemRow1")
    .clone()
    .attr('class', 'itemRow'+ count)
    .appendTo("#itemTable")
    .find(':input')
    .val('')
});
</script>
```

This works fine, The following script is the code that I am having an issue with. It is supposed to be taking the qty field and multiply it with the price field on qty field blur.

It works the first time but once you duplicate the row and try to do it again on that row, it doesn't do it for the second row. But if you change something on the first row, it changes on the second row as well. Which is not what is supposed to happen.

Comment: If you duplicate a row the class .itemRow1 carries over to the next row, correct?

Comment: No I change it to `itemRow`. (`.attr('class', 'itemRow')`) Although, I would like to make it `itemRow2` and so on...

Comment: OK...I see it now...my bad. If you incorporate a for loop (using var i), you can change .attr('class', 'itemRow') to .attr('class', 'itemRow' + i)....but an easier way would be to have a counter of some kind that then adds the value of i

Comment: I can't figure it out... I don't have much experience in java script.

Comment: Try this: add a form in your html and store the initial value of the form as 0 by adding <form id="myForm"><input type="hidden" name="itemRowCount" value="0"></form> then try the following in your function before the jquery (and after the script tag): var itemRowCount = document.forms.myForm.itemRowCount.value; var i = (Number(itemRowCount))++; then try what I suggested...should number your itemRow classes appropriately in each iteration

Comment: Check my updated answer I achieved it with: `var count = $('#itemTable tbody tr').length + 1;` But it doesn't solve what my question was actually about.

Comment: OK...nice edit...I'm looking at your code to try and think of required solution

Comment: How do you distinguish inputs once you have multiple rows? The corresponding input names per row are identical, right? How is your blur function structured to distinguish between different row qty fields and price fields once new rows are created?

Comment: The input names are identical so they submit as an array for processing. I suppose not being able to differentiate between the rows is the problem. Maybe an answer?

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to make sure on blur() that a numeric parameter is added to the blur function so that the array elements for qty field and price fields match up. For example, for the second row, onblur(1) so that when the blur function is called, you are getting item_qty[1] * item_price[1]. I don't have a quality answer to post unfortunately!

Comment: ANYBODY ELSE???????? THIS CAN'T BE THAT COMPLICATED.